# Regex to match String containing at least one digit and one number with specific length

Tags: java, regex

Well, there are million of questions with similiar topic - I have every single response in them but with no success :(

I have set of urls:

```
https://test-gateway.com/newUserCustomerOrder
https://test-gateway.com/newUserCustomerOrder/5e8f39ee5bd0920012e40a13
https://test-gateway.com/newUserCustomerOrder/5e8f39f65bd0920012e40a14
https://test-gateway.com/newUserCustomerOrder/5e8f3a045bd0920012e40a15
https://test-gateway.com/newUserCustomerOrder/5e8fd4755bd0920012e411fd
https://test-gateway.com/newUserCustomerOrder/5e8fd4e35bd0920012e4120b
https://test-gateway.com/newUserCustomerOrder/5e8fd4eb5bd0920012e4120d
```

I would like to find `orderIds` (they will appear in random place inside of this url for particular scenarios)
regex like:

`(?=.*\d)[a-zA-Z\d]{18,24}`

Unfortunately catch both id `5e8f39ee5bd0920012e40a13` and adapter name `newUserCustomerOrder`
I would like to be able to catch each string with length in range `{18,24}` which contains at least one digit.

Could anyone give me a hint how to make it work?

Comment: Use `(?<![^/])(?=[a-zA-Z]*\d)[a-zA-Z\d]{18,24}(?![^/])`, [demo](https://regex101.com/r/pWrC95/1)

Answer (score 2):

Try using the following regex pattern:

```
\b(?=[^/]*\d)\w{18,24}\b
```

### Demo

Explanation of regex:

```
\b           match a word boundary (most likely /)
(?=[^/]*\d)  then assert that a digit follows in the next segment of the URL,
             without passing /
\w{18,24}    match 18 to 24 word characters
\b           match another word boundary
```

Here is a one-liner in Java using this regex:

```
String url = "https://test-gateway.com/newUserCustomerOrder/5e8f39f65bd0920012e40a14";
String orderId = url.replaceAll(".*\\b((?=[^/]*\\d)\\w{18,24})\\b.*", "$1");
System.out.println(orderId);
```

This prints:

```
5e8f39f65bd0920012e40a14
```

Answer (score 2):

Rather than looking ahead for `.*\d`, lookahead for *word characters* followed by `\d`, thus excluding the `newUserCustomerOrder/` since it contains a slash:

```
(?=\w*\d)[a-zA-Z\d]{18,24}
```

https://regex101.com/r/GLrhNd/1

Answer (score 2):

You may use this regex:

```
(?=[^/]*\d)([a-zA-Z\d]{18,24})
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/AauQfV/1)

`(?=[^/]*\d)` is positive lookahead to assert presence of digit following 0 or more non-`/` characters.